# To Make alternating array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am learning the basics and I just cannot hack this one:
This function will be called with an array and should return a new array containing only the alternate elements starting from index 0. If the array is empty or contains only 1 item, return the original array.

```
makeAlternatingArray(['hey', 'hi']);
// should return ['hey']

makeAlternatingArray(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);
// should return ['a', 'c', 'e']
```

What I got so far is:

```
function makeAlternatingArray(array) {
    if (array.length<=1){
        return array
    }
    for (let i=0; i<array.length; i=+2){
        return array[i]
    }
    
}
```

Top part is correct but by for let statement is wrong. I am getting these errors:
When passed an array of multiple elements, function will return an array of alternating items
✕ AssertionError: expected 'a' to deeply equal [ 'a', 'c', 'e' ]

When passed an array of multiple elements, function will return an array of alternating items
✕ AssertionError: expected 100 to deeply equal [ 100, 99, -5 ]

Can someone help please?

```
function makeAlternatingArray(array) {
    if (array.length<=1){
        return array
    }
    for (let i=0; i<array.length; i=+2){
        return array[i]
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `return` exits the function.... So on your for loop it exits. So for a for loop you need to `push` into a new array. Buy you really should just use `filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function makeAlternatingArray(array) {
    if (array.length<=1){
        return array
    }
    return array.filter((el, i) => i % 2 === 0);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

or

```js
function makeAlternatingArray(array) {
    if (array.length<=1){
        return array
    }
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i=0; i<array.length; i=+2){
        newArray.push(array[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, can you explain to me "el"and "i" here? As I didn't learn about this yet want to know what does it stand for so I can use it in future.

Comment: If you look at the link, you'll see that the callback function's first two parameters are `element` and `index`, which I've called `el` and `i`. I didn't need the third parameter, so I didn't declare it.